# HDR say unsupported for two HDR monitors

Tags: windows, hdr

I have AOC AG273QX and Benq EX2780Q both support HDR and Windows 11 HDR was working fine recently I found both reported in windows as HDR not supported how I know the reason for that ?

[image]

Comment: Any recent change to graphics driver? Other updates?

Comment: yes windows 11 updates and AMD driver updates

Comment: HDR could be disabled on your monitor. Also, HDR usually doesnt work under all conditions. Check your monitors manual to see under which conditions HDR might not function.

Comment: It is not disabled.

Comment: Try to rollback the driver updates.

Comment: Are your displays mirrored? [You can't enable HDR in mirrored mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/um15e3/aw3423dw_hdr_not_supported/), only extended mode or when showing on display 1 or 2. Also make sure your cable and ports meet the [requirements for HDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/display-requirements-for-hdr-video-in-windows-192f362e-1245-e14d-3d3f-4b3fc606b80f#ID0EBD=Windows_11), either HDMI 2.0 or DisplayPort 1.4

Comment: @MC10 extended. and it was working fine with current cables I dont know what changes

Comment: emailed AOC and Benq is seems they have no solution